# PyCharm cannot use interpreter in local docker-machine

Tags: docker, pycharm

I am using windows 10 professional and I have installed docker using DockerToolBox, so I have a docker-machine running in VirtualBox. When trying to configure an interpreter in PyCharm using my docker-machine, I get the following error:

"Cannot connect: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri was not specified"

[docker-machine error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctbQU.png)

When I choose 'TCP socket', I get the following error which is different from above:

"Cannot connect: java.io.IOException: Channel disconnected before any data was received"

[TCP socket error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuCVK.png)

I am sure my docker-machine is running because I can connect to it using terminal tools like MobaXterm or XShell, and I can also connect to MySQL running in my docker-machine.

Answer (score 9):

Replacing tcp:// by https:// in the api url works for me in Webstorm (Windows 8.1).

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/580

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me. I'm hosting an secured Docker instance in Photon OS virtual machine.

Comment: This works, it's strange unix:// and tcp:// are the only two "supported protocols". This is a funky implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried thousands of methods, and finally resolved this problem. The solution is running pycharm as administrator. WTF

Comment: That was it! I was scratching my head for to long on this too.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't need to do this... Files created by PyCharm in this case will not be accessible by other users. This will create lots of other problems.

Comment: Same thing for me (phpStorm 2019.3) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.

You must check Pycharm logs. There is detailed information about error.

In my case Pycharm shows same error "Channel disconnected before any data was received".

But in logs i found that error is caused by:
"ERROR - HttpResponseStreamHandlerFixed - exceptionCaught before first read or disconnect, we may be hanging
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching "my_server_hostname" found"

In my case, the problem was that domain name that i connecting to is in not the same as hostname in SSL self signed cert installed in dockerd.

Domain name that you are connecting to must match domain name in SSL cert that dockerd uses.

I have to make hosts record (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows, and /etc/hosts on Linux) and connect to it.

And "https://" protocol is required :)

PS. You can check SSL cert hostname by opening Chrome browser to the docker API endpoint with https and opening certificate details.